# GAE website stopped working on custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname

We have developed a website, which was wroking fine until some days back, but suddenly it stopped working on custom domain. It still wroks fine on appspot subdomain. I rechecked all the settings, they are all okay as per gae guidelines...

- http://www.thesudokutimes.com/ (This one is not working)
- http://thesudokutimes.appspot.com/ (It is accessible here)

Can any one suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: You have notified the appengine group? Make sure your dns is setup and validated properly.

Comment: Some problem, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem related to Google App Engine but to a more generic DNS problem.
Using [Dnsstuff](http://www.dnsstuff.com) tools you can see that your domain name was updated by your Registrar the 23th november 2010 and the IP for [thesudokutimes.com](http://thesudokutimes.com) can't be determined.

I suggest you to double check your configurations and contact your Registrar asking for support.