# Why GAE naked custom domain stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, custom-domain

I've a running Django app served on Google App Engine standard under a custom domain: **mysite.com**.

My site was running pretty well for days but suddenly it stopped serving  content using the custom domain.

**In summary:**

- www.mysite.com => **works**
- mysite.com => **stopped working**

There were no changes in either the DNS nor the app deployment.

**What I've tried:**

First I checked the DNS lookup for these names:

```
a) nslookup my-app.appspot.com   <== the GAE canonical site name
b) nslookup mysite.com           <== custom domain FAILING, ip resolved
c) nslookup www.mysite.com       <== custom domain working, ip resolved
d) nslookup ghs.googlehosted.com <== the recommended GAE DNS entry for www subdomain
```

Surprisingly not only **all the names are resolved correctly** but also they **map to different IP addresses**.

Actually, c) and d) map to the same IP (as expected). Anyway its not a DNS problem as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291556/gae-website-stopped-working-on-custom-domain).

Second, I checked GAE settings to see the custom domain and tried to add another domain: `mysite.com`. But it claimed it was already mapped.

Third, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850747/naked-custom-domain-stopped-working): 
- I deleted the naked domain mapping and re-added later.

Fourth, I've checked documentation and don't find any missing thing in my setup: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?hl=en#top_of_page

Both naked (mysite.com) and 'www.mysite.com' custom domains were working for days!

The current behavior is a bit weird.  Running:

```
wget mysite.com
```

Produces:

`Connecting to mysite.com (mysite.com)|xxx.yyy.zzz.ddd|:443... connected`

Then it hangs for a while and ends with `Unable to establish SSL connection`.

The same happens using the web browser.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Are you getting other messages between **"Connecting to mysite.com (mysite.com)|xxx.yyy.zzz.ddd|:443... connected"** and **"Unable to establish SSL connection"**? This info could be helpful to know what is happening there.

Comment: Hi @eespinola, the connection to the site using **wget** was getting closed. It seemed there was not any backend answering. BTW, the issue got solved using the step 3 and waiting a couple of hours afterwards. A bit weird I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is useful for someone else:

The problem has gone away suddenly, after an hour or so. 
The only change I am aware of is to **delete and register** again the **mysite.com** custom domain entry in the GAE Web cloud console.

The naked domain is now working perfectly.

To avoid getting your site offline:

### How to be alerted about your site's availability

- Enable Stackdriver monitoring by entering into 
  https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring
- Create an uptime check using your site URL
- In Policies: Create an alert policy to be notified by email or app push messages.